# How to create Soap web service in drupal7 using services module and soap_server module?

Tags: php, soap, drupal-7

I have created one RESET web service in drupal7 and it is working fine.
But when i change my server option to soap its give the internal error when i call my web service.
I would like to know how to create the soap web service in drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST web service are basically easily and configurable if soap server module is also depend upon other services module, please check the dependent modules for SOAP config.